# why is my svg javascript ony working partly?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have this 'SVG-menu' that works great in CodePen and here, but only partly on my test site.

What is working is that javascript (1) adds an active state to the SVG-circle (I have styled it with a border) and (2) the `addEventListener` also makes an `innerHTML` with the alt-title in the bottom. Like this

[working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O41m2.png)

What's not working is that (1) the active page (the above) is not staying highlighted (2) the `mouseover` for the new destination page is not highlighted, and (3) the line between the two circles is not highlighted.

[not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0C4Jf.png)

The script seems to be working as parts of it working. It should also be loaded correctly as it is loaded at the end of the body.

It's working [on CodePen](https://codepen.io/gogogagarin/pen/oNWLPPg) as mentioned and also below, but not on my [test site](https://aau.gagarindigital.dk/trans-disciplinary/).

What am I missing?

```js
let allCircles = document.querySelectorAll("circle");
// Add an click handler to every circle that
// adds the class "active" to the clicked circle.
allCircles.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
  element.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseoverHandler);
  element.addEventListener("mouseout", mouseoutHandler);
});

function clickHandler(evt) {
  // Clear current selection (remove class "active" from any circle)
  allCircles.forEach((circle) => circle.classList.remove("active"));
  // Mark clicked circle selected
  evt.target.classList.add("active");
  // Clear any currently highlighted lines
  clearHighlightedLines();
}


function mouseoverHandler(evt) {
  let activeCircle = document.querySelector("circle.active");
    document.querySelector("#pagetitle").innerHTML = evt.target.getAttribute('alt')

  let hoveredCircle = evt.target;
  if (activeCircle && (activeCircle != hoveredCircle)) {
    // Get the line that has classes matching both the actibve and hovered circle
    let line = document.querySelector("line." + activeCircle.id + "." + hoveredCircle.id);
    // Add the class "highlight" to that line
    if (line)
      line.classList.add("highlight");
  }
}

function mouseoutHandler(evt) {
  clearHighlightedLines();
}

function clearHighlightedLines() {
  // Find the line with class "highlight" (if any)
  var line = document.querySelector("line.highlight");
  // Remove the class "highlight"
  if (line)
    line.classList.remove("highlight");
}
```

```css
:root {
        --color-1: #F2B705;
        --color-2: #C30F0E;
        --color-3: #264ABA;
        --color-4: #009CD2;
        --color-5: #E25727;

        
        --color-11: #C29204;
        --color-22: #990B0B;
        --color-33: #172E73;
        --color-44: #006B8E;
        --color-55: #BA4620;
  }
#c1 {
  fill: var(--color-1);
}
#c2 {
  fill: var(--color-2);
}
#c3 {
  fill: var(--color-3);
}

#c4 {
  fill: var(--color-4);
}

#c5 {
  fill: var(--color-5);
}
.cls-7 {
fill: none
    ;
}

#c1.active {
    stroke: var(--color-11);
    stroke-width: 21.5;
}
#c2.active {
    stroke: var(--color-22);
    stroke-width: 21.5;
}
#c3.active {
    stroke: var(--color-33);
    stroke-width: 21.5;
}
#c4.active {
    stroke: var(--color-44);
    stroke-width: 21.5;
}
#c5.active {
    stroke: var(--color-55);
    stroke-width: 21.5;
}
#c1.circle:hover:not(.active) {
  stroke: var(--color-11);
  stroke-width: 21.5;
}
#c2.circle:hover:not(.active) {
  stroke: var(--color-22);
  stroke-width: 21.5;
}
#c3.circle:hover:not(.active) {
  stroke: var(--color-33);
  stroke-width: 21.5;
}
#c4.circle:hover:not(.active) {
  stroke: var(--color-44);
  stroke-width: 21.5;
}
#c5.circle:hover:not(.active) {
  stroke: var(--color-55);
  stroke-width: 21.5;
}

circle.btn1:hover:not(.active) {
  stroke: var(--color-11);
  stroke-width: 21.5;
}
circle.btn2:hover:not(.active) {
  stroke: var(--color-22);
  stroke-width: 21.5;
}
circle.btn3:hover:not(.active) {
  stroke: var(--color-33);
  stroke-width: 21.5;
}
circle.btn4:hover:not(.active) {
  stroke: var(--color-44);
  stroke-width: 21.5;
}
circle.btn5:hover:not(.active) {
  stroke: var(--color-55);
  stroke-width: 21.5;
}

line {
  stroke: #c1c1c1;
  stroke-width: 22;
}

line.highlight {
  stroke: black;
}
.title {
  text-align: center;
}
#pagetitle {
    font-size: 4em;
}
/*
circle.active {
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 11.5;
}
*/
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-10 -10 940 910">

   <defs>
    <style></style>
    
  </defs>
       <polygon id="fem-kant" class="cls-7" points="456.29 7.49 898.87 329.05 729.82 849.33 182.76 849.33 13.71 329.05 456.29 7.49"/>

      <line class="c3 c5" x1="656.32" y1="748.57" x2="133.5" y2="368.62"/>
      <line class="c2 c4" x1="258.55" y1="747.22" x2="779.33" y2="368.43"/>
      <line class="c1 c4" x1="258.55" y1="747.22" x2="457.43" y2="133.5"/>
      <line class="c1 c3" x1="457.43" y1="133.5" x2="657.03" y2="748.57"/>
      <line class="c5 c2" x1="133.5" y1="368.62" x2="779.33" y2="368.43"/>
      <line class="c1 c2" x1="779.33" y1="368.43" x2="457.43" y2="133.5"/>
      <line class="c2 c3" x1="779.33" y1="368.43" x2="657.03" y2="748.57"/>
      <line class="c3 c4" x1="258.55" y1="747.22" x2="657.03" y2="748.57"/>
      <line class="c4 c5" x1="258.55" y1="747.22" x2="133.5" y2="368.62"/>
      <line class="c5 c1" x1="133.5" y1="368.62" x2="457.43" y2="133.5"/>

  <a href="#0">
      <circle id="c1" class="btn1 btn" alt="one" cx="455.9" cy="133.5" r="133" data-Name="shape 1" data-tabindex="0" />
        </a>
  <a href="#0">
      <circle id="c2" class="btn2 btn" alt="two" cx="779.33" cy="368.43" r="133" data-Name="shape 2" data-tabindex="0" />
            </a>
            <a href="#0">
                <circle id="c3" class="btn3 btn" alt="three" cx="656.32" cy="748.57" r="133" data-Name="shape 3" data-tabindex="0" />
            </a>
  <a href="#0">
      <circle id="c4" class="btn4 btn" alt="four" cx="256.18" cy="748.57" r="133" data-Name="shape 4" data-tabindex="0" />
            </a>
            <a href="#0">
                <circle id="c5" class="btn5 btn" alt="Application" cx="133.5" cy="368.62" r="133" data-Name="shape 5" data-tabindex="0" />
            </a>
<script>
    
    
</script>
    </svg>
<div class="title">
    <p id="pagetitle"> </p>
</div>
```

Comment: In your codepen, all your links have `href="#0"` only, meaning you never actually leave the current page by clicking them. On your site however you are really linking to different pages. So you would have to determine what the “active” item is supposed to be, each time one of those pages loads.

Comment: That makes sense - but how do I determine the “active” item?

Comment: Depends on whether you want to do it on the server or the client side. Do a bit of research, there should be plenty to find to get you started.

Comment: This is what came up in my research:


`
 var menuItems = document.querySelectorAll("bnt");
 
   for(i=0; i < menuItems.length; i++){

         menuItems[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
           
           for(i=0; i < menuItems.length; i++){
              menuItems[i].parentElement.className = '';
           }
           this.parentElement.className = 'act';
         }, false);

   }
`

But it doesn't work out of the box. Can anybody help with placing it with the `clickHandler`?